# Javascript statements all to be evaluated

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

Hi I want each if statements to be evaluated (java script). This is not happening, when one or two are true the remaining statements are not evaluated. They are all independent questions. What should I be using instead of if and else? Thanks.

```
//Side-Vent-Even
if (SideVent == "Side-Vent-Even" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
// do this
}

//Side-Vent-Uneven
else if (SideVent2 == "Side-Vent-Uneven" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
// do this
}

//Golf-Tee-Right
else if (GolfTee == "Golf-Tee-Right" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
// do this
}

//Golf-Tee-Left
else if (GolfTee2 == "Golf-Tee-Left" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
// do this
}
```

Comment: Just use `if` instead of `else if`.

Comment: Remove the `else`. Just use `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn them in to regular ifs, which will cause them all to be run independently of each other

```
if(){
}
....
if(){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If else are used when you wish to perform condition from either of them but not both or all, in your case you want all of them to be performed, hence use if condition statement for all, like

```
//Side-Vent-Even
if (SideVent == "Side-Vent-Even" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
  // do this
}

//Side-Vent-Uneven
 if (SideVent2 == "Side-Vent-Uneven" && Canvas=="Base-Shirt") {
  // do this
}
```